# Writing program, importing three float a, b and c. sort in ascending order

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float a,b,c,maxx,minn;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    maxx=a;
    if (b>maxx) (maxx=b);
    if (c>maxx) (maxx=c);
    minn=b;
    if (a<minn) (minn=a);
    if (c<minn) (minn=c);
    cout<<minn<<" "<<maxx ;
}
```

I don't know how to print the number between `max` and `min`.

Comment: Imagine you have 4 floats instead: you have to write much more code. You need a more general approach.

Comment: @Wolf Tbh, I dont know how to do it though I've been searching for many times.

Comment: For instance, try inserting the values into a `vector`. vectors can be sorted by the `sort` algorhithm. Both, `vector` and `sort`, are in the namespace `std` but need their own `include` statements, search the web for it.

Comment: @Wolf -- the assignment is to sort **three** variables, not to write a generalized sort function.

Comment: In order to talk about the order of three values you need to have something that implies order. For a case like this, use an array: `std::array<float, 3> values;`. Read the values into the three locations in the array, then look at two values at a time and move them around until they're in order.

Comment: You may want to use another variable for the value between `minn` and `maxx`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use stl containers and algorithms whenever possible. This saves you a lot of work and problems. There already exists a function for your problem. In your description you ask for a sorting of the values. In the provides code you only ask for min and max. The min/max solution would be:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<float, 3> a;
    std::cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2];
    auto [a_min, a_max] = std::minmax({a[0], a[1], a[2]});
    std::cout << "Min: " << a_min << "\nMax: " << a_max << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

`std::minmax` expects a list of values and returns a `std::pair` with min and max. It won't change the container. `auto [a_min, a_max]` is a structured binding that stores the first value of the pair in `a_min` and the second value in `a_max`.

Here is a solution for the sort problem

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<float, 3> a;
    std::cin >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2];
    std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
    for (const auto &el : a) {
        std::cout << el << ' ';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`std::sort` expects an iterator to the beginning and an iterator to the end of your container. It will sort your actual container and don't provide a sorted copy. The range-based for loop

```
for (const auto &el : a) {
```

is a simply way to iterate over your container.

Also to fix your current code you can add a new variable:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    float maxx = a;
    if (b > maxx) { maxx = b; }
    if (c > maxx) { maxx = c; }
    float minn = b;
    if (a < minn) { minn = a; }
    if (c < minn) { minn = c; }
    float midd = c;
    if (a > minn && a < maxx) { midd = a; }
    if (b > minn && b < maxx) { midd = b; }
    std::cout << minn << ' ' << midd << ' ' << maxx;
}
```